# Disable Profile Creation on Firefox

Tags: firefox, security, user-profiles

Is it possible to disable new profile creation in Firefox? Or password protect new profile creation?

The problem is there is no point in installing say site blocking add-ons because anyone can create a new profile and access any site they want.

Comment: Are you aware of other problems with this approach to parental control? Like, the user may simply delete the add on file from the profile?

Comment: Instead of site-blocking firefox addons, try something like Pi-Hole. Still, anyone can easily evade this kind of blocking by simply pasting the URL in google translate or using a webproxy or one of the thousands of other methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't give your users administrator access, then it should be enough to revoke write privileges on

```
c:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini
```

The location of this file may vary depending on your setup.

Note that this file is straightforward, so you can keep control of what profile is loaded as well.

Site blocking is best done at the perimeter however.

Comment: This approach unfortunately doesn’t work. Even if you revoke write perms on this file, it is still possible to create a new profile and immediately use it. The profile won’t be registered in this file though, so it won’t appear in the Profile Manager next time, but hey, nothing stops you to create a _yet_ another profile. This way, by creating throwaway profiles each time you start Firefox, you can bypass the parental control add-on.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to disable new profile creation in Firefox?

Yes. If an instance of FireFox is already running, you can not access FireFox's internal profile-manager.

> Or password protect new profile creation?

No. It is not possible to prevent the creation of a new profile in Profile-Manager from inside Firefox or the Profile-Manager. Balnk, forced and administrative profiles are not part of the system anymore since the revamp of Firefox, because the new version is only supported on operating-systems with User/Rights-Management and the old method does contradict that.

> The problem is there is no point in installing say site blocking add-ons because anyone can create a new profile and access any site they want.

This is very confusing. Because first it seemed that you are talking about the Firefox-Application-Profiles, which allow you to setup and store independent profiles to save custom sets of Add-Ons, Settings, Layouts and so on.

Site-blocking-Add-Ons is a broad term, but in the end regardless of what technique they use they are still add-ons and are specific to the active Firefox-profile. Whereas also if this add-on makes use of cloud-support to store their configuration they are bond to the active user, meaning attached to the Firefox-Sync registered User.

Please provide more details, e.g.: Which branch/edition/version of Firefox as it does make a difference - ESR is completely different from stable, as well as Developer is completely independent from both.

If you wish to prevent access to the Firefox-Profiles manager you need to do this on the system-level. An application can by design not be able to prevent the creation done by a separate application (the Firefox profile manager). This has to be done via User/Group/Application-Rights-Management.

In Windows NT this would be Group-Policies and/or ActiveDirectory depending on the type of user and network-management used on the host and related clients and servers in the network.

In Linux this would be SELinux, in case of RPM-based distributions like RHEL, Fedora, OpenSuse, SLES, etc.; in Ubuntu-based distributions it would be AppArmor.

Please clarify what is a given in your environment.

As an exercise, for Windows it would be possible to do this without using GroupPolicies by forcing Firefox to start on boot and write a worker for example with AutoHotKey/AutoIt/etc. which binds to the event of opening the Profile-Manager and either prevent input/selection/changes or otherwise manipulate it to make it inaccessible.

Another hack would be to start Firefox on boot and abuse the behaviour of the included Firefox-Error-Reporting tool, which allows you to auto-send reports and automatically restart Firefox to bring up a new instance. While this still could be overridden by overloading the system to interrupt this process, it is still viable and for example done as a safeguard in Windows Embedded installments.

In any case please provide specifics so a direct answer is possible.